# SQLAlchemy One-to-One relationships

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a `File` class:

```
class File(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'files'

    id        = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name      = Column(String)
    mime_type = Column(String)
    data      = Column(LargeBinary)
```

which I use for storing attachments in my application.  I also have a `Note` class:

```
class Note(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'notes'

    id   = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    note = Column(String)
    fid  = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('files.id'))

    file = relationship('File', uselist=False, cascade="all, delete-orphan")
```

where `fid` can be `NULL` if the user has not attached a file.  In addition to `Note` other classes also make use of an `fid` column for handling attachments.

However, I am wondering how I can make the creation of a note more elegant.  Specifically, I would like to be able to do something like `Note(note=note_text,file=File(...))` and have SQLAlchemy take care of inserting a new entry into `files`.  Similarly, for an existing `Note`, I would like to be able to do `n.file = File(...)` or `n.file = None` and have everything just work with there being no orphaned entries in `files`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy will persist all your `Note` and `File` objects in database session, assigning foreign keys appropriately during `Session.flush`. There isn't anything else you need to do besides defining the `relationship`s correctly (which, as I can see, you have already done).

Comment: I had to add `single_parent=True` to get this working, but otherwise it is as you describe.